# Browserify: take minified file from node module

Tags: javascript, browserify

I installed bootstrap via npm and i'd like to require it via browserify, so I use:

```
require('bootstrap');
```

But there are 2 problems here:

1. It takes the non minified version of bootstrap
2. I would also like to include the `bootstrap.tpl.min` file

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately browserify won't solve either of those problems for you.  NPM packages are meant to be small and solve one problem well and browserify's domain is resolving all the dependencies you require and packaging them up into one file for the browser.

Minification of your bundle should happen as part of your build step using [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) or [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) using a package like [uglify](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS).

Including a template file will also require some additional work if it's not included in what's exported from bootstrap.  You can either require the specific file from the module if you need access to it in code, or you could copy it to the directory that you're serving up either with your build tool or using [bower](http://bower.io/)